# ActiveRecord Query Not Returning

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

I have a query in my Rails application that should return a specific user (I've triple-checked, the user passes all of the variables), but it instead returns nothing. Here is my query:

```
User.all.where("created_at < ? AND created_at > ? AND completed = ? AND id != ? AND auto_renew = ? AND lower(promo) != ? AND enrolled = ?", "#{6.months.ago}", "#{7.months.ago}", "false", "1", "true", "promo", "true").order("created_at ASC")
```

I don't know where the problem lies, I've researched it for hours. Any help would be appreciated!

**EDIT:**

Here is the user that is supposed to show up:

```
<User id: 29, email: "urmum@gm.com", created_at: "2017-07-26 17:58:02", updated_at: "2018-01-26 17:58:03", enrolled: true, progress: 0, first_name: "ur", last_name: "mum", street: "", city: "", state: "", zip: "", school: nil, referral: "", age: "10-15", phone: "", image_file_name: nil, image_content_type: nil, image_file_size: nil, image_updated_at: nil, card_number: nil, card_name: nil, card_exp_year: nil, card_exp_month: nil, card_cvv: nil, promo: "", two_week: false, completed: false, banhammer: false, auto_renew: true, subscribed: true, stripeid: "cus_CD1VQGTRLXSha0", subsriptionId: "sub_CD1VmVG7RsqRju">
```

Comment: you don't need quotes on any of those arguments. `"true"` should be just `true`.

Comment: Actually doesn't change anything. I've alternated between either. Still the same result.

Comment: Take out nearly all the quotes - especially the `"#{6.months.ago}"`. Just pass `6.months.ago` and ActiveRecord will figure out what you mean

Comment: I've tried that, too

Comment: Run your website in development mode, run `rake log:clear` to erase the log, hit the button that runs your query, read the log, find the SQL SELECT statement you generated, and try it in `bin/rails dbconsole` directly. If that still does not help, post the SELECT statement here.

Answer (score 2):

I think it may be because you are calling `created_at < ? AND created_at > ?` and passing in `"6.months.ago", "7.months.ago`

So Rails is trying to find a user that was created less than 6 months ago AND more than 7 months ago which there is none.  A user can only be either created less than 6 months ago OR created greater than 7 months ago.

Take out one of the created_at statements and see if it works.  something like this.

```
User.all.where("created_at < ? AND completed = ? AND id != ? AND auto_renew = ? AND lower(promo) != ? AND enrolled = ?", "#{6.months.ago}", false, "1", true, "promo", true).order("created_at ASC")
```

Comment: The user has to be between 6 and 7 months, though. Those have passed in users that are between the 6-7 month range before, but it won't do it now.

Comment: I think you would need to flip the signs to make it find a user between a certain date, so something like `where("created_at >= ? AND created_at <= ?",  7.months.ago, 6.months.ago)`

Comment: you could also try `where("DATE(created_at) BETWEEN ? AND ?", 7.months.ago, 6,months.ago)`

Comment: I don't think that's the issue, as it can find other users between that time frame without trouble.

Comment: I've updated my question with the user I am trying to return.

Answer (score 1):

You should try this:-

```
User.all.where("created_at < ? AND created_at > ? AND completed = ? AND id != ? AND auto_renew = ? AND lower(promo) != ? AND enrolled = ?", "#{6.months.ago}", "#{7.months.ago}", false, "1", true, "promo", true).order("created_at ASC")
```

You are passing the boolean values as a string parameter which active record don't understand.

Comment: Actually doesn't change anything. I've alternated between either. Still the same result.

Comment: @Collin are you sure there is some user created under this particular time interval which satisfies all the criteria mentioned in the query, as query don't have any issues.

Comment: I've updated my question with the user I am trying to return.

Comment: @Collin above added user falls under this query. Only reason in my thinking would be if User model is having any **default scope**  which is creating issue.

Comment: Would that be under `user.rb`?

Comment: Yes default scope are written under model file in your case its **user.rb** . Default scope apply on all the query you fire on that particular model.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
User.where.not(id:1).where.not("lower(promo) = ?","promo").where(created_at:6.months.ago..7.months.ago, completed:false, auto_renew:true, enrolled:true).order(:created_at)
```

I recommend you move the promo's to a different model

Comment: Thanks for this. It didn't work immediately, but was something to go off of. I had to swap out the 7 & 6 months, and then that worked. Interesting thing, though, I played around with using `"true"` instead of just `true` on the exact same query, and it would return different users. Any idea why this might be and how to fix it? They are supposed to be **booleans**.

Comment: When you use "true", you are basically comparing bool with a string, since type of "true" is string

Answer (score 0):

I have changed condition to find user created between 6 month and 7 month ago a little bit and remove unnecessary double quotes which can lead to the issue. Let try below query:

```
User.where("created_at BETWEEN ? AND ? AND completed = ? AND id != ? AND auto_renew = ? AND lower(promo) != ? AND enrolled = ?", 6.months.ago, 7.months.ago, false, 1, true, "promo", true).order("created_at ASC")
```

Answer (score 0):

A couple of tips:

1. Add `.to_sql` to your query (or just watch the output in rails console in dev mode), inspect the sql and make sure it makes sense. Specifically, you may have `default_scope` that modifies your query in a way that excludes your user (maybe `default_scope where(completed: true)`. Just guessing).
2. Add `and id = 29` to your query so you are only returning your user and start removing your conditions one-by-one. The one that when removed results in it returning your user is the offending one.